# jQuery fadein fadeout repeatedly

Tags: jquery, fade, fadein, out

I have a image and in it wants to be fadein fadeout automatically when the document is loaded and it should be done till the document is closed ..
help me plzz

Comment: So youre trying to replicate the abhorrent blink element in JQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this'll do it:

```
$(function () {
    $('#fader').fadeIn('slow', function () {
        fadeItOut();
    });
});

function fadeItIn() {
    $('#fader').fadeIn('slow', function () {
        fadeItOut();
    });
}

function fadeItOut() {
    $('#fader').fadeOut('slow', function () {
        fadeItIn();
    });
}
```

with

fader being the id of your image

Comment: +1 for the answer, even though I can't say I approve of the effect.

Answer (score 3):

```
$( function() {
    var t = 500;
    setInterval( function(){
        $('#id').fadeOut( t, function(){ $(this).fadeIn( t ); } );
    }, 2*t);
});
```

`id` is the image id and `t` is the interval.